# Search for the longest sequence of toggled consecutive bits in an integer

Tags: c, bitwise

I have to do a function ​called `findsaw`. This function searches for the longest sequence of toggled consecutive bits in an integer and returns the index of the first bit of the sequence, the sequence must start from the least significant bit.

In the case there are multiple answers(sequences with same size) choose the one with lowest start index.

Function signature:

```
unsigned int findsaw(int value)
```

Some test cases:

- `findsaw(0x0)` returns **0**
- `findsaw(0xAA)` returns **0**
- `findsaw(0xA0F)` returns **8**
- `findsaw(0xF0A)` returns **0**
- `findsaw(0xFA0)` returns **4**
- `findsaw(0xEAEA476BL)` returns **23**

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define YES 1 /* inside a sequence */
#define NO 0 /* outside a sequence */

unsigned int findsaw(int value){
    unsigned int sequence = value;
    unsigned char idx = 0;
    unsigned char sequenceIdx = 0;      
    unsigned char currentIdx = 0;      
    unsigned char size = 0;             
    unsigned char sequenceSize = 0;     
    unsigned char bit = value & 1;      
    unsigned char nextBit;              
    unsigned char insideSequence = NO;  


    while (sequence){   
        sequence>>= 1;
        nextBit = sequence & 1; 
        if(bit ^ nextBit){
            if(insideSequence){ 
                sequenceSize++;
            }
            else{
                sequenceSize = 2;
                sequenceIdx = currentIdx;
                insideSequence = YES;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(size < sequenceSize){
                size = sequenceSize;
                idx = sequenceIdx;
            }
            insideSequence = NO;
            sequenceSize = 0;
        }
        currentIdx++;
        bit = nextBit;
    }
    if(size < sequenceSize){
        idx = sequenceIdx;
    }
    return idx;
}
```

What would be the correct output for all 1's like `findsaw(0xF)`, my function returns the index of the last bit, in this case 3?

Comment: One observation: If you already have a function that will find a sequence of identical bits, you can transform the input by XOR with 0x5555... (to the length of your type) or 0xAAAA... and then the problem is equivalent.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't understand your observation can you explain it better in an answer?

Comment: The two masks given by @TobySpeight are alternating binary sequences: zero-one-zero-one... or one-zero-one-zero-... So if you XOR one of them with your number, every alternating subsequence would be converted either into a contiguous block of zeros or a block of ones.

Comment: Input like `0xF` is **not** 'all 1's' because it actually is `0x0000000F` for 32-bit `int`, hence 3 is a correct answer: the longest chain of alternating bits in the given number is a two-bit sequence `01` at positions 4 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we make any changes, let's add some tests to the end, so we have confidence that we don't break anything that worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int test(unsigned int value, unsigned int expected)
{
    unsigned int actual = findsaw(value);
    if (actual == expected)
        return 0;
    printf("findsaw(%#x) = %u\n", value, actual);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    return test(0x0, 0)
        +  test(0xAA, 0)
        +  test(0x585, 0)
        +  test(0xA0F, 8)
        +  test(0xF0A, 0)
        +  test(0xFA0, 4)
        +  test(0xEAEA476Bu, 23);
}
```

This all passes (the program returns 0).  I made `test` take the value as an unsigned int, because `0xEAEA476B` is too big for a plain int on my system.

---

Now let's look at your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define YES 1 /* inside a sequence */
#define NO 0 /* outside a sequence */
```

We're not using anything from `<stdio.h>`, so that's not required.  Also, instead of defining `YES` and `NO` in the preprocessor, we could include `<stdbool.h>`, and then use `true` and `false` instead.

```
unsigned int findsaw(int value) {
    unsigned int sequence = value;
```

Are you required to accept input as a signed integer?  If not, then declare `findsaw()` to take an `unsigned int`.  As it is, the last test case (from the question's code) produced a compilation warning, as `0xEAEA476BL` is larger than `INT_MAX` on my system.

```
unsigned char idx = 0;
unsigned char sequenceIdx = 0;
unsigned char currentIdx = 0;
unsigned char size = 0;
unsigned char sequenceSize = 0;
unsigned char bit = value & 1;
unsigned char nextBit;
```

None of these really need to be `char`.  It's probably better to let them be `int` (or `uint_fast8_t` if you're really keen).

These names aren't immediately obvious to me (or to you in six months' time).  It might be worth grouping them so that `idx` and `size`, which represent the best match so far, are placed together, with a comment explaining that.  Similarly, `sequenceIdx` and `sequenceSize` seem to represent the current in-progress match, and should go together.

Some of the naming was alien to me: I'd have considered what you call the "next" bit to be "current", and what you call just "bit" to be "last_bit".  That might be just me, though.

```
    if (bit ^ nextBit) {
```

A comment would be nice here: this is true when we're matching the sawtooth pattern.  Also, the `else` branch contains actions that are only needed immediately at the end of a sequence, and do nothing for extended runs such as 0x00 or 0xFF, so that can be `else if (insideSequence)`.

We can save a bit of work here:

```
        /* matched a transition */
        if (insideSequence) { /* just add to the size */
            sequenceSize++;
        } else {
            /* initialize for inside a sequence */
            sequenceSize = 2;
            sequenceIdx = currentIdx;
            insideSequence = true;
        }
```

If we initialise `sequenceSize` to `1` instead of `0`, then we can simply increment it in both cases (i.e. outside the `if`).  We can use `sequenceSize == 1` to determine whether we're in a sequence, and we no longer need the `insideSequence` variable (nor `<stdbool.h>`):

```
unsigned int findsaw(unsigned int value) {
    unsigned int sequence = value;

    /* best match so far */
    unsigned int best_start = 0; /* this is what we're looking for */
    unsigned int best_size = 0;

    unsigned int sequenceIdx = 0;
    unsigned int currentIdx = 0;
    unsigned int sequenceSize = 1;


    while (sequence) {
        const int last_bit = sequence & 1;
        sequence >>= 1;
        const int current_bit = sequence & 1;
        if (last_bit ^ current_bit) {
            /* matched a transition */
            if (sequenceSize++ == 1) {
                /* the start of a new sequence */
                sequenceIdx = currentIdx;
            }
        } else if (sequenceSize != 1) {
            /* not matched - did we just finish a sequence? */
            if (best_size < sequenceSize) {
                best_size = sequenceSize;
                best_start = sequenceIdx;
            }
            sequenceSize = 1;
        }
        ++currentIdx;
    }
    if (best_size < sequenceSize) {
        best_start = sequenceIdx;
    }
    return best_start;
}
```

Let's see if we can do anything about the duplication of `if (best_size < sequenceSize)` when we reach the last bit.  I'll add a couple of extra tests:

```
    +  test(0x50000005u, 27)
    +  test(0xA0000005u, 0)
```

The last one fails (returns 28), because we are zero-extending the left of the value, but not the right.  If we simply take out the test, then other test cases fail (`0xa0f` and `0x50000005`).  It seems that the `while (sequence)` returns too early in those cases.

---

At this point, I give up fixing this and look at a different approach.  We don't need to check `last_bit ^ current_bit` every time around the loop - we can compute them all at the same time like this:

```
unsigned int sequence = value;
unsigned int mask = sequence ^ (sequence >> 1);
```

This produces a 1 everywhere we have a bit preceded by its complement.  We still have the problem that the high bit might be set, but we can fix this by writing `mask = sequence ^ (sequence << 1)` to make the low bit the stray one, and we can just shift that out.  Now, all we have to do is find the longest run of 1s:

```
unsigned int findsaw(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int sequence = value;
    unsigned int mask = sequence ^ (sequence << 1);

    /* best match so far */
    unsigned int best_start = 0; /* this is what we're looking for */
    unsigned int best_size = 0;

    /* current run */
    unsigned int current_start = 0;
    unsigned int current_size = 0;

    /* current position */
    for (unsigned int i = 0;  mask >>= 1;  ++i) {
        if (mask & 1) {
            if (!current_size++)
                /* the start of a new run */
                current_start = i;
        } else if (current_size) {
            current_size = 0;
        }

        if (current_size > best_size) {
            best_size = current_size;
            best_start = current_start;
        }
    }

    return best_start;
}

#include <stdio.h>
static int test(unsigned int value, unsigned int expected)
{
    unsigned int actual = findsaw(value);
    if (actual == expected)
        return 0;
    printf("findsaw(%#x) = %u\n", value, actual);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    return test(0x0, 0)
        +  test(0xAA, 0)
        +  test(0x585, 0)
        +  test(0xA0F, 8)
        +  test(0xF0A, 0)
        +  test(0xFA0, 4)
        +  test(0xEAEA476Bu, 23)
        +  test(0x50000005u, 27)
        +  test(0xA0000005u, 0);
}
```

All the tests pass; time to go home.

Comment: Are you required to accept input as a signed integer? Yes.